# Delete object with a function contained inside it

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js

I've been struggling on this for some hours now and I can't seem to get that done. I'm using Vue(JS).

So, what I'm trying to do is push some notifications inside a Object and then displaying them to the user. Each notification has its own function to display things when clicked and then to delete itself after. The latter I can't quite figure out.

I'm basically taking advantage of Vue's reactive properties.

I already searched a lot trying to find a manner to delete a object with it's own function, but I found nothing so far.

The reason I'm not using the `@click` to also delete its object is because I want to have control of whether the action inside the notification is fullfilled and only then delete it.

I've made a simplified JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/319133/

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    notifications: [
      { 
      text: "Some notification", 
      action: function() {
        alert("Something 1");
          // And then delete this object entirely, so that this notification's gone
        }
      },
      { 
      text: "Another notification", 
      action: function() {
        alert("Something 2");
          // Same as above
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
.notification {
  background-color: #bbb;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  
  width: 200px;
  transition: .1s ease;
}

.notification:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  (Click on one)
  
  <div class="notification" v-for="notif in notifications" @click="notif.action">{{ notif.text }}</div>
  
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Review the [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function for arrays. Please note that questions on Stack Overflow benefit from having a [mcve] in the question itself, not just on an external site.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I've included the code, so it now runs as a code example on SO, but now for the problem: How can slice 'know' on which index the notification is? The function should be executed inside its own object.

Comment: Why does it need to execute in its own object? Why can't it call an external function that removes it from the `notifications` array? You could add a unique `id` attribute to the objects in the array and pass that to the external function.

Comment: @HereticMonkey In theory yes, but how do I access the 'id' inside the object, but outside of the 'function'? I still need to know the own index, which I don't know how to do.

Comment: I'd do something like `externalFunction(this.id)` inside the `action` function. Then in `externalFunction(id)` do `notifications.splice(notifications.findIndex(item => item.id === id), 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like [that](https://jsfiddle.net/ug6w7v38/).

When you use v-for and you manipulate the array displayed, better add `:key` (id can be auto-generated).
It helps Vue to displayed correctly the items.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    notifications: [
      { 
      id: 0,
      text: "Some notification", 
      action: function() {
         return confirm("Something 1");
          // And then delete this object entirely, so that this notification's gone
        }
      },
      { 
      id: 1,
      text: "Another notification", 
      action: function() {
          return confirm("Something 2");
          // Same as above
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
   processNotif(index) {
       const notif = this.notifications[index];
       const result = notif.action();
       if (result) this.notifications.splice(index, 1);
    },
  }
})
```

```css
.notification {
  background-color: #bbb;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  
  width: 200px;
  transition: .1s ease;
}

.notification:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  (Click on one)
  
  <div :key="notif.id" class="notification" v-for="(notif, index) in notifications" @click="processNotif(index)">{{ notif.text }}</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this seems interesting, I may give it a try later, but your example is kind of 'upside down', I click on one and it deletes the other.

Comment: My bad, I fixed it.

Comment: Now it works. But there might be a caveat mentioned in the question: You delete the object before the action is fullfilled. 'alert' hold the execution of the script until you close it, but in the real thing it isn't a 'alert', which means when I click the notification, the object will vanish before I even made something with the notification. It should only delete itself after completion (the last line of the 'action' function).

Comment: It is sequential so the action will be completed before it is deleted. However, if it is some ajax requests, well, may be this action should be in processNotif and not in the notif itself

Comment: What if I don't fullfill the 'action' (pressing 'Cancel' on some fancy dialog that'll pop up), how do I leave the notification there?

Comment: Well, let the method `action` returns boolean, if true, remove from array, if false, do not remove... I update my snippet, check it.

Comment: Yes, that should work. I think I just figured out yet another way with this example. Letting 'action' take one argument and then passing it its own index. Then at the end of the 'action' I put a slice with that passed argument, which is the index. Your approach is better when dealing with the same scope, but when using promises and stuff, slice with a argument, as I mentioned, might be better. Either way, it should be solved now. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the object from the notifications array using [normal array mutation methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

array

```
notifications: [
      { 
      text: "Some notification", 
      action: function() {
            //
        }
      },{ 
      text: "Some notification", 
      action: function() {
            //
        }
      }
]
```

remove an object from an array

```
let index = 1
notifications = notifications.slice(index)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how do I know the index *inside* the function? It basically needs to know its own index.

Comment: The answer above shows how you can pass the index from within the `v-for` loop :)